# 500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred(0): Unknown data property field_group_privacy

Tags: php, rest, drupal, server, drupal-nodes

I am trying to Create Services to Create Node Type Discussion in a Group using Services Module, but getting the error :

```
500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred(0): Unknown data property field_group_privacy
```

In the Header I have given:

```
Content-type:application/json

x-csrf-token:token value

session-name:session name value
```

In the Body I have given :

```
{
"og_group_ref": {"und": [{"target_id": "3897"}]},

"title": "Title of discussion",

"field_description": {"und": [{"value": "test description"}]},

"type": "discussion"

}
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error ?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77ZZn.png)

Answer (score 0):

The service you are posting the data to has an error in it's code. It's probably trying to do something with a field called "group privacy" that doesn't exist. Or the query to look at that data is invalid

Comment: The field group privacy don't exist here :
> admin/structure/types/manage/discussion/fields

But there is field with this name here :
> /admin/structure/types/manage/group/fields

So its the problem at server side, I am POSTing the data correctly ?

Comment: An alternative could be the server is expecting you to send a "field_group_privacy" data field which is missing in your posted data. The server should really be able to handle missing data rather than failing and creating a 500

Comment: I tried to give this in body but still the same error : "field_group_privacy":{"und":[{"value": "0"}]},